# Self Knowledge, Is this site not promoting Ego by adding followers and who is popular?

Tags: discussion

I just want to learn about Hinduism and ask question not for being Popular or winning followers. I am merely an ignorant person with many questions. If I let my Ego become inflated with popularity of I asked the best Question etc. It takes me away from my dedication of true learning.
Forgive me I am not going to participate in those kinds of thing but wish to learn as this site seem to provide so many good Blogs.
Thanks you

Comment: This site does not have a mechanism to follow or friend a user. Votes indicate usefulness of content and are meant to be strictly impersonal, and points unlock moderation abilities that allow you to be involved in janitorial work on the site as you learn about it, in theory. That's the ideal. Of course, there are [unfortunate side effects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation/93343)

Comment: This is not a Hindu site. It is a site about Hinduism. There is a big difference.

Comment: this is meta question instead

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to be offensive at all. Do not have knowledge what a Meta site is. I do know the difference about Hindu site and about Hinduism. I chose to focus on Hinduism. If I want other things from this site I will chose to go there.